# How do I search for a table in sql 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, search, qsqlquery

I just created a table within a huge database and saved it. I've tried to refresh the database to see if my new table appears and I closed & reopened the Management Studio but don't see my new table. I was wondering if there is a way to search for my new created table? I'm using SQL Server 2005. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[table_name_here]')
```

or try this:-

```
 USE YourDBName
 GO 
 SELECT *
 FROM sys.Tables
 where name like '%tablename%'
 GO
```

Comment: Thanks all! This was my ssolution: 
 USE Database_Name
 GO

 SELECT * 
 FROM Table_Name

Answer (score 3):

```
 Select * from sys.tables where name like '%tablename%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If table doesn't appear, check under different schema.

select * from sys.all_objects where name like '%tableName%' and type = 'U'